# CSS border-radius

Tags: css

```
<style>
  div {border-radius:5px;background:#cccccc;}
  span {display:block;}
</style>

<div>
    <span>First line</span>
    <span>Second line</span>
</div>
```

I want each `span` to fit inside the `div` with rounded corners, but they go in front of the div and obscure the rounded corners. If I put rounded corners on each `span` then you can see a faint outline of each `span`, even if they have the same `background-color` as the `div`.

Comment: what browser do you use? Works well for me in firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try overflow:hidden on the div? or give it a z-index of 1000

Answer (score 2):

alternative to @AlexC's answer:

```
<style>
  div {border-radius:5px;background:#cccccc;}
  span {padding:0px 5px;display:block;}
  .topspan {padding:5px 5px 0px 5px;display:block;}
  .bottomspan {padding:0px 5px 5px 5px;display:block;}
</style>

<div>
    <span class="topspan"></span>
    <span>First line</span>
    <span>Second line</span>
    <span class="bottomspan"></span>
</div>
```

see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/32yUR/)

Answer (score 0):

If you give the `div` a padding you will push the content from the borders of the div so they will never overlap. This usually looks nicer anyway.

```
div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background:    #ccc;
    padding:       5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 span {display:block;padding:0px 10px;}
```

[Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kbxnz/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't add add border radius for span, bcoz span is default `display:inline` in type.

So you need to change `display:block` or `display:inline`

all credit goes to:
[http://www.cssstylekit.com/CSS-Border-Radius.html](http://test.cssstylekit.com/CSS-Border-Radius.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
 .demo-border-radius {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
</style>
<div class="demo-border-radius">border radius div</div>
```